# Creating different random objects from the same class

Tags: java

I have a class called country and i want to generate two different random countries at the same time

This is the method in the class to get a random country.

```
Country a = Country.getRandom();
```

How i could get two different countries?

Answer (score 5):

```
Country a = Country.getRandom();
Country b = Country.getRandom();
```

You can't do two things at the same time. Java executes your statemetns sequentially.
What you can try is to have a `getRandom(int)` method which takes an `int` and returns that many random `Country` objects in a `List` for example.

**Edit**

Method overloading is basically providing two methods with the same name but different parameter list:

```
public Country getRandom() {
    // ...
}

public List<Country> getRandom(int resultCount) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: but this method doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: You can overload it to do so.

Comment: How i can do that ? because this is an assignment and we didn't yet take the overload you talking about.

Comment: Sorry i still can't get it. Isn't there any other way to do it ?

Comment: Sorry I give up. I suggest you should wait until your teacher explains it.

Answer (score 4):

By this way

```
Country a = Country.getRandom();
Country b = Coutry.getRandom();
```

Alternatively you could do this with an array.

Make the method pass values in array form. That way you'd have two variables.